# Indefinite Integral Question - What kind of substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I've been trying to solve this integral for the past two hours, but haven't gotten anywhere:

$$ \int \frac {dx}{2\sqrt{x-4}+x} $$

I've tried various kinds of substitutions to no avail. Even just a prod in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Try the "rationalizing substitution" $ \ u^2 \ = \ x - 4 \ \ , \ \ 2u \ du \ = \ dx \ . $  The quadratic polynomial in the denominator will be irreducible, so you will have to follow with "completing the square".  The anti-derivative function will involve logarithmic and arctangent terms, more'n'likely...

Comment: That's one ugly integral. The solution is disgusting.

Comment: @Shahar You'll see worse... **much** worse... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best best is to start with the substitution $x-4=u^2$ to get

$$\int{2u\,du\over2u+(u^2+4)}=\int{2(u+1)-2\over(u+1)^2+3}du$$

Can you take it from there?  (You should get a logarithm and an arctangent in the final answer.)

Comment: I found the logarithm (ln|x+2sqrt(x-4)|/2), but I'm having a bit of trouble getting to the arctangent.

I know that the identity for arctan is 1/(1+x^2), but whenever I try to take that from:  
$$ \int \frac {1}{(u+1)^2 +3} $$  
I get something wrong. I'm trying to factor out the 1, so what I have looks like:
$$ \frac 13 \int \frac {1}{(\frac{u+1} {\sqrt3} )^2 +1} $$  

So I get:

$$ \frac{arctan( \frac {u+1}{\sqrt3}^2)}{3} $$  
(I've factored out the -2 in the numerator)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The remaining substitution is $ \ v \ = \ \frac{u+1}{\sqrt{3}} \ \ , \ \ \sqrt{3} \ dv \ = \ du \ . $  So you are close, but should have $ \ \frac{\arctan v}{\sqrt{3}} \ . $  Incidentally, in your logarithmic term, the denominator of "2" gets written as a term " $ \ - \ln 2 \ $ ",  which is then "swallowed" by the arbitrary constant of the indefinite integral.  (That's why you won't see it in a textbook or online-solver's answer.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! :)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, thank you.  I was away for several hours after posting my answer, so didn't see the OP's follow-up query till just now.

Comment: No problem -- just a final detail.